# How to create a matrix from a given list without using Numpy in Python

Tags: python, matrix, random

I checked the solution in [Creating a Matrix in Python without numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120892/creating-a-matrix-in-python-without-numpy) but this only address square matrixes. That is 3x3 or 4x4.

For example, I tried the answer in those questions with the following lines and it gives list index out of range error.

```
random_list = random.sample(range(10,99), 10)
print(len(random_list))
mat = createMatrix(5,2,random_list)
print (mat)
```

My question is given a list with numbers, how to put it into a matrix.

e.g.

```
column = input("No of Column: ")
rows = input("No of Rows: ")
randomDataList = random.sample(range(10,99), int(column)* int(rows))
createMatrix(int(column), int(rows), randomDataList)
```

Comment: The first answer in that question would seem to work perfectly well for non-square matrices.

Comment: I edited the question. See where I found it fails.

Comment: Oh, yes, it looks like there's a bug. I commented on the original question, but repeating it here: Changing `rowCount` to `colCount` in the innermost portion of `createMatrix`'s for loop should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of list comprehension:

```
import random
column = input("No of Column: ")
rows = input("No of Rows: ")
n, m = int(rows), int(column)
randomDataList = random.sample(range(10,99), n*m)
print([[randomDataList[i+m*j] for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)])
```

Comment: 2 nested for loops too much of a stretch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to build a list of lists -

```
import random

r, c = 4, 5

l = random.sample(range(-10,10),r*c)

matrix = [l[i:i + int(r*c / c)] for i in range(0, len(l), int(r*c / c))]
print(matrix)
```

```
[[-10, -4, 7, 4], [1, 9, -5, 6], [-8, 5, 3, -9], [-2, 2, 8, -7], [0, -6, -1, -3]]
```

Comment: Cannot use Numpy

Comment: Numpy has not been used for the solution. Only to generate the random input list that has to be converted to a 'matrix'

Comment: `np.random.random`, unlike `random.sample`, does not return unique numbers here.

Comment: My bad. Yes, got it.

Comment: Updated my solution just because. @MarioIshac - So?